# Making one layout still visible regardless on another view/layout switch

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have two XML layouts, for example "menu_layout" and "game_layout". On app start, the view is set to "menu_layout" via setContentView(R.id.menu_layout). Just after this line, I'm creating another layout - "top_layout", which I need to make it always on top (stay visible), regardless on view switch.

That means, when the view is switched to from "menu_layout" to "game_layout" and vise versa, the "top_layout" is still visible and isn't affected by that.

Any idea how do I create this "top_layout" with these parameters?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single activity with top_layout and then have container below where you can switch fragments using FragmentManager.

Similar results can be achieved manually using dynamically added and removed views from the container, fragments are more helpful when you need to handle more complex scenarios with multiple replaced views and also back stack and you don't want to do it yourself.

**Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
<include layout="@+id/top_layout" />

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

**Fragments (2x):**

```
public static class GameFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_layout, container, false);
}
```

}

**Fragment add:**

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     MenuFragment fragment = new MenuFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**Fragment switch:**

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    GameFragment fragment = new GameFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Docs:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html